# Shorten a Powershell cmdlet Output property result

Tags: powershell

I have an example query in Powershell;

```
Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | 
Format-Table -Property Name, Managed By
```

Result

```
Name      : OsDisk_1_dfa60a
ManagedBy : /subscriptions/resourceGroups/Company/Microsoft.Compute/vms/Server1
```

---

The output for the managed by Property is too long.
I want to shorten it,  to the characters after the last `/` (forward slash)
Intended Result

```
Name      : OsDisk_1_dfa60a
ManagedBy : Server1
```

---

So far i have tried to use substring, and Last index of to count the index of "/" and start the substring there, then end the substring at the full  length of the ManagedBy property string;

```
Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | 
Format-List -Property Name, 
ManagedBy.SubString(ManagedBy.LastIndexOf('/'),ManagedBy.length)
```

errors ensue: ManagedBy.LastIndexOf : The term 'ManagedBy.LastIndexOf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,

---

Solution

```
   Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | 
Format-Table -Property Name, 
@{Name='ManagedBy';Expr={$_.ManagedBy.Split('/')[-1]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give  you what you want...

```
Format-List -Property Name, 
@{Name='ManagedBy';Expr={$_.ManagedBy.Split('/')[-1]}}
```

Comment: Missed a closing brace.

Comment: Mike, What is this process called,  "@{Name=' - i want to look it up and learn more. Thanks for your time

Comment: The `@{Name=...` is a calculated property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6 or https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If...

```
$ManagedBy = "/subscriptions/resourceGroups/Company/Microsoft.Compute/vms/Server1"
```

Then...

```
$LastResult = $ManagedBy.Split("/")[$ManagedBy.Split("/").Length - 1]
```

Which returns just the last value, in this case `Server1` by itself, in the array.  Arrays start from a position of 0 (zero), so you have to only go 1 step from the end of the `Length` of the array.

In this case, change the `ManagedBy` property to be the value of `$LastResult`, which you should be able to incorporate into the rest of your code.